# Is every ideal in $K[X]$ generated by monomials $x_1^{d_1}x_2^{d_2}\cdots x_n^{d_n}$, where each $d_i$ is a power of $p$, finitely generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $K$ be a field of characteristic $p$, where $p$ is a prime. Consider the ring $K[X]$ of the polynomials in the variables commutative and $X=\{x_1,x_2,... \}$. Is every ideal in $K[X]$ generated by monomials $x_1^{d_1}x_2^{d_2}\cdots x_n^{d_n}$, where each $d_i$ is a power of $p$, finitely generated?

Comment: $K[X]$ is not a Noetherian ring, therefore there exist at least one ideal that is not finitely generated. Is this ideal generated by monomials where its exponents are powers of $p$  finitely genereted?

Answer (score 2):

Of course not; consider the ideal $(x_1^p,x_2^p,x_3^p,\ldots)$.

Comment: Again, as you did twice [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3888110/242) today, you have repeated a hint from a comment (15 minutes prior) into an answer, without attribution.

Comment: @BillDubuque Just no, really.