# Finding a positive integer that can't be expressed in a certain form

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers

I attended a math speech and the speaker left the following question as an exercise:

> Which positive integer cannot be expressed in the form $$x^2+2y^2+5z^2+5w^2?$$

I've trying to solve it but I haven't accomplished it yet. Any help is welcome

Comment: Unexpectedly, all you have to do is check the positive integers up to $15$, because if there isn't one by then that can't be represented, there never will be! https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FifteenTheorem.html

Comment: @GregMartin  Indeed, you have to go all the way to $15$ for this particular form.

Comment: @GregMartin Well $15$  can't be so represented, so what does the theorem say?  Does it tell what all the exceptions are?

Comment: @saulspatz  A variant of the $15$ Theorem holds that if the (suitable) quadratic form represents all the positive integers less than $15$ then it represents all the integers greater than $15$ (so that $15$ is the only omitted natural number for this case).  See, e.g., [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20140814082644/https://math.stanford.edu/theses/moon.pdf)

Comment: @lulu Thanks.  Starting at about 12:45 in [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JybQ-6OTrLQ) J.H. Conway discusses the history of this particular form.  He says that astonishingly, Ramanujan included it in a list of $55$ universal quadratic forms.

Comment: @saulspatz  Ah, didn't know that.  Actually, I have no idea how Conway proved the thing.  If memory serves, he never published that.  The proofs I know of all follow the lines given by Bhargava, not Conway.

Comment: @lulu I remember hearing somewhere that he never published it, and when Bhargava asked hm about it, he had forgotten the proof, so Bhargava proved it himself.  I think Conway talks about that in the lecture, but the audio is really bad, and I'm not sure.  If I understood it properly, Conway was able to tell Bhargava the general methods he used, but not the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are very few integers that are perfect squares, and none of them are negative. So we can order them starting from the smallest one, as $0$, $1$, $4$, $9$, $16$, $25$, etcetera. Now for any given positive integer $n$, there are only finitely many candidates for the squares $x^2$, $y^2$, $z^2$ and $w^2$ because all the coefficients are positive. Simply check them all to see whether $n$ can be expressed in this way.

Of course there is seemingly no guarantee that you will ever find a positive integer $n$ that is not of this form, even if it exists. But there is a wonderfully surprising theorem, the [fifteen theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FifteenTheorem.html), that states that *if* every positive integer up to $15$ can be expressed as such a sum of squares, then *every* positive integer can be expressed as such a sum of squares. So the approach described above only requires you to check up to $n=15$ to find a positive integer not of this form, if it exists.

A quick check shows that every integer $n<15$ is of this form, but that $n=15$ is not. A more precise version of the fifteen theorem then tells us that every integer $n>15$ is also of this form, thanks to lulu's comment with [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140814082644/https://math.stanford.edu/theses/moon.pdf). So $n=15$ is the unique positive integer not of this form.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote?

Comment: Make that downvote**s**.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes either. In my opinion you gave a good answer.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but given that this method was already mentioned 10 minutes earlier in a comment by Greg Martin (and you didn't give any credit), may be one potential reason. I think the best thing to do in cases like this is to explicitly mention the comment, and then add something *nontrivial* beyond the comment(s).

Comment: Further, your edit "a more precise..." also incorporated lulu's later comment without any credit. This is poor netiquette.